# Using ScriptSharp to code YUI controls

Tags: javascript, yui, javascript-framework, script#

I am in the process of choosing ScriptSharp for coding all my javascripts. I already use JQuery and it is great that there is built-in support for this.

But what about YUI? I need it in particular for the editor control..

How can I code the part for the editor control within Script# framework? Is there a place to enter custom javascript when a certain library is not supported or something similar?

Are there any future plans to add YUI to ScriptSharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be interesting to have YUI support, but there aren't specific plans to add support for it right now, at least not at the top of the priority list.

However, if folks in the community want to get it going and contribute, I can help with questions that come up.

The general idea is you create an import library (there is an Import Library project template when you install Script#), which defines a c# API corresponding to the OM that you program against. The C# API consists of classes and stub methods that define the signatures (think of this as a header file of sorts). There are a few metadata attributes to customize generation of script that references those APIs to get various transforms to happen ... so you can create a working, and often times more natural c# interface that then maps to runtime script constructs and APIs you are targeting.

When I see the sample at http://yuilibrary.com/ I see a bunch of parallels to jQuery, so I imagine building support for it is likely possible at a technical level.

The best way to understand how to do this would be to look at the sources of mscorlib.dll (represents the core script objects) Script.Web.dll (represents the DOM) and Script.jQuery.dll (represents core jQuery API). All of these are in the Script# repository on github ... https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp ... if you haven't already seen them.

Comment: Thank you. That helped, I created an import library project and I'll add the functions as I need them. If I get anything worthwhile I'll try to share and let other continue the work I did. Now I have another question, but I'll open a new thread.

Comment: @Durden81.. any updates on this?  Would be interested in hearing more about this honestly.  I'd like to get jQuery UI and KnockoutJS int Script# so then it'd be practical to implement in a project I'm on.

Answer (score 1):

We are creating an import library for OpenLayers (http://openlayers.org) and I can say it is incredible easy to do. We started just doing what NikhilK says, inspecting the source code. The results are just great. YUI is a very well designed and documented api, so I think it would be stratightforward. You could just create the import clases you need for your project.